# Powershell - Select name from array and send email to DL

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm very new and still learning the ropes on Powershell/scripting in general. I'm doing a simple task for my team which should do the below.

- Each Monday it will go through the list of team members, picks one name and sends email with that one name to an DL.
- I want I have set the names as a variable from a txt file using Get-Content.

What I need help with is trying to figure out how I can get PS to select a name from the variable ($name) each week.

For example, the names would be like:
John R
Jim B
Sam W
Ron C
Vincent W

I would like the "send-mailMessage" body to include only one of the names each week. I will schedule the script to run each Monday morning. But i'm not sure on how I can make it choose 1 name and move to the next name the following week?

I have a base script I've written which basically creates a variable "$name" from a txt file, have done the basic email SMTP settings and Sen-MailMessage body to include the sub-expression for name. Just need help to work out how I can select 1 name from the list.

Is my logic right or is there a better way I can do this?

(also first post here, let me know if I should do things differently on future posts)

EDIT:
Here is what I have at this moment:

`$names = Get-Content -Path "C:\scripts\list.txt"
#SMTP settings
$emailpw = ConvertTo-SecureString "*********" - AsPlainText -Force
$emailsmtp = "emails.domain.com"

$mailsender = "Sender Email <noreply@domain.com>"
$mailbox= "Receiver <receiver@domain.com>"

#Send Email
Send-MailMessage -to $mailbox -from $mailboxsender -Subject "example 
subject" -body "This is a body using variable $($name) etc..." -BodyAsHtml 
-priority High -credential $emailcred -SmtpServer $emailsmtp`

Comment: "I have a base script I've written which basically" <== You should add this script as part of the question, and format is as code.

Answer (score 0):

On on my mobile, so I don’t have code for you, but if you really need to cycle through the names I would write the index of the name I am working with to a text file.  The first run should look for the file, and when it doesn’t find it, start with 0 and write it to the file. The next run should see the file and add 1 to the retrieved value. If the value exceeds the array upper bound you go back to 0. If names are added or removed it will make this not work quite right.  I would also sort the names before starting this process so they are always in the same order.